# How do I group data into a column by a common feature?

Tags: r

[image]

I have a huge list of genes separated into clusters.  As in the image, the cluster IDs and the genes are in separate columns.  What I'd like to do is create a new data frame using the cluster IDs as the column `names/headers`, then have the genes be the rows below each column name.  For example:

```
cluster 0
Ccl5
Trbc2
Cd3g
Nkg7
etc
```

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `spread` function from the `tidyr` package. Assuming your data is called `df`:

```
library(tidyr)

spread(df, key = cluster, value = gene)
```

Comment: spread has been [superseded](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function `pivot_wider` from the `tidyr` package to convert your data from long to wide by doing something like:

```
new_dataframe <- old_dataframe %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = cluster,
              values_from = gene)
```